# How I deserialize a dynamic json property with RestSharp in C#?

Tags: c#, json, dynamic, deserialization, restsharp

I have a web service (I can't edit) with this structure:

**/users**

```
{
    "response" : {
        "users": [{"name": "John"},{"name": "Jack"}]
    },
    "page" : { "current":1, "total":1}
}
```

**/pets**

```
{
    "response" : {
        "pets": [{"name": "Fido"},{"name": "Tweety"}]
    },
    "page" : { "current":1, "total":1}
}
```

As you can see the property name in the "response" property changes.
How can deserialize a generic response with RestSharp? I don't want to write a Response class for every resource.

I have written the following generic Response class

```cs
class RestResponse{
    public ResponseBody response { get; set; }
    public ResponsePage page { get; set; }
}

class ResponseBody {
    public List<dynamic> resourceList { get; set; } 
}

class ResponsePage {
    public int current { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
}

class User { public string name {get; set;} }

class Pet { public string name {get; set;} }
```

Of course RestSharp can't link the dynamic json property with the ResponseBody.list attribute. 
How can I do this?

Answer (score 6):

I'll start with saying that is not elegant at all:

You can get the raw JSON response using

```
RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
var jsonString = response.Content; // raw content as string
```

From there on, you can query it using [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm) like that:

```
var jObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
// this could probably be written nicer, but you get the idea...
var resources = jObject ["response"]["users"].Select(t => t["name"]);
```

`resources` would then hold a list of your names. This is ugly, inflexible, and I wouldn't recommend it.

Better stick with clever inheritance and custom classes. Its much more readable and your response object will probably not all only have one property, right?

Comment: Actually I was asking for a way to avoid inelegant approaches like this :-p